# HCI/UX Design Blogs

Tags: user-interface, blogs, user-experience

I'm interested in learning more about HCI design decisions and practices, but I haven't been able to find any consistent source of articles on the subject: Many blogs have an article or two on the subject, then go off and talk about something else. I would stick to web design blogs, but videos like [this one about Firefox 4 tab design](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmgtW2Iw-kE) provide evidence that there is a lot of interesting ground to cover in desktop application design. Anyone know where I should get started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web journal [UXMatters](http://www.uxmatters.com/) recently listed the [favorite blogs of various UX experts](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/06/favorite-ux-technology-blogs-learning-about-new-web-mobile-applications.php). For that matter UXMatters is an excellent resource for UX design.

The following sites frequently have articles giving concrete UX design guidance specifically applicable to the web:

- [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/). Gets into the nuts and bolts of web design and development
- [Bokardo](http://bokardo.com/). Social design in web apps.
- [Boxes and Arrows](http://www.boxesandarrows.com/). Another journal emphasizing IA.
- [Brain Sparks](http://www.uie.com/brainsparks/). Especially UIEtips articles.
- [Functioning Form](http://www.lukew.com/ff/). Especially for articles on web form design.

There's more on [my blogroll](http://www.zuschlogin.com/) under "usability," although those remaining sites (like my own) tend to lean towards general application UI design, rather than web site design specifically.

Comment: General UI design is what I'm more interested in at this point: I'm an avid reader of a lot of web-specific design blogs

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps user-interface design patterns will help. I find that sources are consistent and patterns well-documented.

A good number of resources can be found here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at the following books. These are pretty much the standard for any one looking to get good information about HCI. You need to understand the core principles first.

1. The Design of Everyday things - Donald Norman
2. The inmates are running the asylum - Alan Cooper
3. The Humane interface - Jeff Raskin
4. How things work - Donald Norman
5. Designing Web Usability: The Practice of Simplicity - Jackob Nielsen

If you want to get more into the science of why:

Principles of cognitive psychology - Eysenck